# How can I create https ssl certificate and integrate with Angular4?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, https, ssl-certificate

I have create a server side with Spring boot and Spring security with https.

Followed the following url
https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

So now I want to access https urls from my client Angular4 application.

But its not woking. What are the steps i need to follow to make it work?

Do I need to create a self-signed certificate for this?
If yes how can I create the certificate with `mykeystore.jsk and mykeystore.p12`

Comment: What isn't working specifically? Do you get an error when trying to do an https call? If your certificate is configured properly Angular should just work with https. No further configuration is required on Angular's side (except possibly changing the protocol in the url).

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the cert and key using this: https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a

and then in package.json set npm start to what your key/cert files are like this:

```
ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-key "ssl/local.brianflove.com.key" --ssl-cert "ssl/local.brianflove.com.crt"
```

Comment: While the link may contain the answer, it's better to provide the full answer here.